# google map using Angularjs is not working in live app

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to create an angular app with Intel-XDK

I have latitude value in $scope.latitude and longitude value in $scope.longitude.what I need is when I click on ngclick() the map will be open outside the application.Here in my code map is working in intel XDK.but when I host the application it  is not working.

Index.html

```
<div class="item item-divider" style="font-size:18px;">
   <i class="icon ion-map"></i> &nbsp;
   <a ng-click="launchGoogleMaps()">Location map</a>
 </div>
```

App.js

```
app.controller('main', function ($scope,$interval,$ionicModal,localStorageService,$http,$q,$templateCache) {

    <div class="item item-divider" style="font-size:18px;">
       <i class="icon ion-map"></i> &nbsp;
       <a ng-click="launchGoogleMaps()">Location map</a>
     </div>
});
```

Comment: It is impossible to tell from this tiny snippet what the issue is.  You forgot to copy in your app.js as well.

Comment: @DavidL I had wrote this much code only for google map, and it is working successfully in Intel-XDK.But the problem is when I host it is not working

Comment: There are a myriad of issues as to why it might not be working.  For one, Google could be blacklisting you. Have you checked with them to make sure that they're allowing traffic from your host?

Comment: plunkr or fiddle please.

Comment: @DavidL This is an android app using XDK.We just want to open the google map on google app.nothing more.

Comment: @sherinks Understandable, but we still don't have enough information to help you.  As Satej said, please provide some sort of plunkr or fiddle that reproduces the problem.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8fm6w0m7/1/ @DavidL

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/8fm6w0m7/1/ @SatejS

Comment: @DavidL but I am confused that it is working with local app, but why its not working with live app?

Comment: @sherinks My guess is that you're minifying when deployed live and not minifying locally.

Comment: I have only this much line for google map, and its working also.

Comment: @DavidL this is the same code I am using for live app

Comment: When you say its working do you mean that it works in the browser or it works on your emulator?

Comment: Yes@Zargold its working in local browser and also Intel-XDK

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply open google map by changing index.html.No need to write javascript

```
div style="padding-left:10px;">
                         <i class="icon ion-map"></i><a href="http://maps.google.com/maps?ll={{temple.latitude}},{{temple.longitude}}">
                         Location Map</a>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect syntax:

```
app.controller('main', function ($scope,$interval,$ionicModal,localStorageService,$http,$q,$templateCache) {

    <div class="item item-divider" style="font-size:18px;">
       <i class="icon ion-map"></i> &nbsp;
       <a ng-click="launchGoogleMaps()">Location map</a>
     </div> //especially this part...
});
```

It would be hard for anything to work if you don't have proper syntax you will get copious syntax errors here.

After looking at your fiddle: you defined url twice with var each time what is the point of that?
Also, what commands did you run in the command line did you do like ionic build ?

Comment: sorry mistakenly I wrote url twice.pardon me @Zargold

Comment: Its working in locally.when I click on onclick() the google map[ is opening.but when I host it is not working @Zargold

Comment: My application is not only for google map.have huge code.so so many things is missing in fiddle. @Zargold

Comment: yes but I mean does it work in Safari/Chrome or is it working locally on the actual Intel device locally?

Comment: Its working in all the browser like firefox,chrome etc and also working in Intel-XDK too

Comment: Ok so when is it not working like the API doesn't work? perhaps it is because you are using the full URL when trying to use the app: like `"http://myserver.com/api/thingies"` MUST be used when launching on a public api versus `"/api/thingies"`

Comment: Is any other option to open google map in live if I have latitude and longitude value @ Zargold

Comment: Is the only thing that isn't working the google Maps? but the rest of the App works perfectly "publicly"?

Comment: @ Zargold we dont want to host app now.so now we didnt call API. what I need is we just want to open google map from my android app

Comment: @ Zargold my exact problem is I cant open google app  from android app

Comment: My app is working perfectly in Intel-XDK but when I debugging with android devide Map is not working @ Zargold

Comment: on debugging when I click on onclick() it shows error like intel is not defined.so I install intel-XDK-plugin.but it give the warning like depreciate plugin. @ Zargold